# root path issues when server is run as a daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, daemon

i have several views, as well as some gems, that access the filesystem.  this seems to work fine until i run the server as a daemon. *rails (4.2.3)*

for example in one of my views I access the README file in the root of the app

```
File.read('README.md')
```

when running as a daemon, i get the error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - README.md`

the error page shows the Rails.root path, which is correct.  i CAN fix this problem by doing:

```
File.read("#{Rails.root}/README.md")
```

however this issue breaks more than just my views. It would seem an issue with the rails server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how daemonized process works - `chdir` to / or another working directory. Some programs allow you to specify working directory for daemon process. For example `puma` server uses current directory by default so it might work for you.

Comment: Yeah i guess this was more of a rails server question than a daemon question. but that makes sense that a daemon should run without the need for context. There are some gem's that break when running as a daemon, so I suppose it is the gem's responsibility. Thanks for the clarification!