# Rails server daemon working directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I found out per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095871/root-path-issues-when-server-is-run-as-a-daemon#answer-31096935) that when you run:

```
rails server -d
```

Rails decides that its `Dir.pwd` is `/`. So when trying to read a file on the system, I need to execute with full path of said file (`File.read("#{Rails.root}/path/to/file"`). How can I tell Rails to set `Dir.pwd` to `Rails.root`

Comment: I think that Dir.pwd is not from Rails. It's comes from Ruby: `http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't able to figure this out using `rails s -d` alone. Ended up going with Phusion Passenger: `passenger start -d`

Solved my issue

Comment: Passenger is a much better system for hosting production sites anyway. Good call.